# Swift - Closure pattern

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dependency-injection

I'm reading docs about Swinject and I don't understand two things in this code :

```
let container = Container()
container.register(AnimalType.self) { _ in Cat(name: "Mimi") }
container.register(PersonType.self) { r in
    PetOwner(pet: r.resolve(AnimalType.self)!)
}
```

How the to two closures are standing alone and are not embeded in method call ?
The closures are not returning any object, I don't see any 'return'. So how the container can get the "Cat" instance ? ( And also the PetOwner instance ).

Thank you

Comment: See [the documentation on Swift closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) – notably the sections on "Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures" & ["Trailing Closures"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102)

Comment: @originaluser2 thank you, It's perfect !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *"two closures are standing alone and are not embeded in method call"*

This is so called "trailing closure":

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing closure is a closure expression that is written outside of (and after) the parentheses of the function call it supports...

*Source: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102)*

2. *"The closures are not returning any object, I don't see any 'return'"*

The feature is called "implicit return":

> Single-expression closures can implicitly return the result of their single expression by omitting the return keyword from their declaration...

*Source: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID99)*